# Stop HTML5 audio from playing when device is locked (Android & iOS)

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm developing a HTML5 game that has looping music and sound effects. I'm using the [soundjs library](http://www.soundjs.com) from the [createjs suite](http://www.createjs.com).

When I minimize the browser on Android devices and iOs devices the sounds continue to play. This is even the case when the device is locked! This is also the case cross browser, (Safari, Chrome, Android Native, Firefox)

Is there a simple fix for this, or is detecting the page being inactive and disabling the sounds a more likely solution?

---

I tried this, thinking that the timeout would fire when the page was closed but it doesn't. :(

```
var timeout = -1;
setInterval(function(){
     if(timeout!=-1) clearTimeout(timeout);
     timeout = setTimeout(function(){
         AudioManager.setMute(true);
     }, 200);
, 100);
```

Comment: Have you tried using the [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/User_experience/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API)?

Comment: @ThiefMaster I have not, it look's interesting but not supported by enough devices. only supported by the latest mobile operating systems iOS version 7, and android 4.4. http://caniuse.com/#search=visibility

Comment: SoundJS does not handle this internally.  I was going to recommend the Page Visibility API as well, to detect the page losing focus and disable the sounds in response.  Goo luck.

Comment: @OJay I understand this. The Page Visibility API seems like the best (ONLY) solution. even though it has poor compatibility cross platform. It's only supported by android 4.4 (KitKat, which hasn't been released yet) and iOS7 which has only just been released. So this solution would only actually fix the issue for 25% of users (using Google Analytics from previous released game)

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me is the following (using jQuery v2.1.4):

```
// Declare soundtrack as SoundJS object
soundtrack = createjs.Sound.play("main", {loop: -1});

$(window).focus(function() {
    // Unpause when window gains focus
    soundtrack.paused = false;
}).blur(function() {
    // Pause when window loses focus
    soundtrack.paused = true;
});
```

Whenever the Safari window loses focus, it'll pause the soundtrack. When it regains focus, it'll resume. Worked for me on iPhone Safari iOS 9.